# Maze algorithm python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, graph-theory, maze

Turn the four rings so that the sums of each four of the numbers that are located along the same radius are the same. Find what they are equal to?
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0naU.png)

We can do it by **Brute Force** method but it will be dummy cause too many combinations.
I had thoughts about **DFS method** but cant imagine how to consume it here truly.
I dont need code for this problem, perhaps you can share your thoughts on this issue.

```
input data

1-st ring: 3 9 6 4 3 7 5 2 4 8 3 6
2-nd ring: 8 4 7 5 8 2 9 5 5 8 4 6
3-rd ring: 6 5 8 1 6 6 7 1 3 7 1 9
4-th ring: 9 2 4 6 8 4 3 8 5 2 3 7
```

Comment: You know exactly the sum of each radius and the max and min of each ring. That allows you to somewhat prune the search tree. The problem is that the wheels are so small that brute force will probably be faster than any theoretical smarter algorithm.

Comment: Thx for feedback, have done this problem with simple brute force as you told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have done this problem without using any theoretical algorithm using python.

Just simple **Brute Force method** like **walking through my rings** starting from 2-nd one**

```
def find_radius(*args):
    arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(args[0])):
        sum_radius = args[0][i] + args[1][i] + args[2][i] + args[3][i]
        arr.append(sum_radius)

    return list(dict.fromkeys(arr))


def move_ring(arr):
    first_element = arr[0]
    arr.remove(first_element)
    arr.append(first_element)
    return arr


def print_all_rings(*args):
    print(args[0])
    print(args[1])
    print(args[2])
    print(args[3])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # first example
    
    ring_1 = [3, 9, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6]
    ring_2 = [8, 4, 7, 5, 8, 2, 9, 5, 5, 8, 4, 6]
    ring_3 = [6, 5, 8, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1, 3, 7, 1, 9]
    ring_4 = [9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 3, 7]

    # second example
    
    # ring_1 = [4, 2]
    # ring_2 = [6, 8]
    # ring_3 = [9, 8]
    # ring_4 = [5, 8]

    first_round = 0
    second_round = 0

    while True:
        if first_round == len(ring_1):
            first_round = 0
            move_ring(ring_3)
            second_round += 1

        if second_round == len(ring_1):
            second_round = 0
            move_ring(ring_4)

        if len(find_radius(ring_1, ring_2, ring_3, ring_4)) == 1:
            print("200 OK! All subsums in column are the same")
            break
        else:
            print("404 Error!")

        move_ring(ring_2)
        first_round += 1

    print(find_radius(ring_1, ring_2, ring_3, ring_4))
    print_all_rings(ring_1, ring_2, ring_3, ring_4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean by brute force, but I don't think you can avoid trying all combinations (which is exactly what a tree search does as well).

Note though that since only relative displacements matter, it is enough to search on displacements of 3 rings. You can do so using backtracking (which exactly corresponds to a tree search).

Comment: Dont think its called backtracking but I just simple trying all combinations. I search displacements of 3 rings (starting form 2-nd one) as you have mentioned.